# Creating a variable for the distance between one node and all other nodes

Tags: r, igraph

In R using the igraph package, how would I create a variable that's the distance between one specific node and all other nodes?

Here's what I have so far.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

employees = read_csv("employee_list.csv")
EmpsSups = data.frame(employees$employee-name, employees$supervisor)

graph = graph_from_data_frame(EmpsSups, directed=F)
```

The data consists of a table with the first column (employee-name) containing the names of all company employees. The second column (supervisor) contains the names of each employee's direct supervisor. I'm trying to find the distance between the company director (`Smith, John` in the code below) and all other employees.

Using `shortest_paths` gave me the following result:

```
shortest_paths(graph, "Smith, John", "Pike, Robert")
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 7/2415 vertices, named, from 921848a:
[1] Smith, John      Dia, Paul       Pent, Kate         Wilson, Todd   Jones, Tim          
[6] Zelensky, Jason        Pike, Robert


$epath
NULL

$predecessors
NULL

$inbound_edges
NULL
```

What I'm essentially looking for is something that would give me the 7 from the `7/2415 vertices` bit. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

igraph has this function built-in. It is called `distances`.

Here is a quick example.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(271828)
g = erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.2)

## Get the distances from node 6 to all others
distances(g, 6)
```